# How to remove spaces at the beginning and end of SfCartesianChart

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I'm using [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) to create graphs in flutter but an unknown spacing is there at the beginning and end of the chart like this

[image: this]

here is my code,

```
SfCartesianChart(
  crosshairBehavior: CrosshairBehavior(
    enable: true,
    lineType: CrosshairLineType.vertical,
    activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
    lineDashArray: [2, 2],
  ),
  primaryXAxis: const CategoryAxis(
    majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  ), // Initialize category axis.
  series: <AreaSeries<Map<String, dynamic>, String>>[
    // Initialize line series.
    AreaSeries<Map<String, dynamic>, String>(
        borderColor: graphThemeColor,
        borderWidth: 1.spMin,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              graphThemeColor.withOpacity(.2),
              Colors.transparent
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        dataSource: graphValues,
        xValueMapper: (Map value, _) => value['x'],
        yValueMapper: (Map value, _) => value['y'])
  ],
)
```

How to remove that padding?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1):

For the primaryXAxis as CategoryAxis, the default value of the labelPlacement property is LabelPlacement.betweenTicks, which positions the axis label between the ticks. Therefore, the padding is applied between the start and end of the axis label. To avoid this behavior, you can set the labelPlacement to LabelPlacement.onTicks, which positions the axis label directly on the ticks. We have provided a code snippet and output for your reference.

Output Screenshot:

[image: Output Screenshot]

Code snippet:

```dart
  primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
  labelPlacement: LabelPlacement.onTicks,
  majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
    color: Colors.transparent,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my employer doesn't want me to use a package with commercial license. So I switched to [fl_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart)